# react authentication through spring security. Possible ?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, spring-security

I am new to React programming.

Is it possible to do authentication with Spring security ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you looked at this blog? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-react